# Specify location of actions on popup in ArcGIS SDK JS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript v4 how can I specify that I want actions to always show underneath the content? On [the examples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-custom-action/) the actions always show above the content, no matter where the clicked feature appears on the map:

[image: example map, top feature, action above content] [image: example map, bottom feature, action above content]

However on my own map with my own popup and custom actions, the actions show above the content if the feature is in the top half of the map and below the content if the feature is in the bottom half of the map:

[image: own map, top feature, actions at top] [image: own map, bottom feature, actions at bottom]

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Sorry, can't do it, since I already voted for closing it because of lack of code. But you can simply delete it.

Comment: Requested duplicate reference: [Controlling position of popup's actions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336454/controlling-position-of-popups-actions)